# Apply a copy of an object to each disconnected curve using the curve modifier

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, procedural, curve-modifier

The curve modifier allows you to specify a curve object for a given mesh with the modifier applied. However, when the curve object itself has multiple disconnected curves, the modifier seems to pick just one curve.

Is it possible to have a copy of the object for each disconnected curve? A solution with geometry nodes would also be nice; unfortunately, it doesn't look like there's any way to use geometry nodes to deform a mesh along a curve.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a somewhat limited version of the `Curve` modifier that only works on the X axis (it is possible to make it work on other axes, I just got lazy). It trims the curve to fit the object's length, then deforms the object to mimic the curve's shape.

[image]

The *Curve Index* socket on the `Sample Curve` node allows us to pick which spline (each curve branch inside a larger *Curve* object) we want to use for the deformation:

[image]

You could simply use multiple copies of this modifier node with different curve indices and merge them with a `Join Geometry` node, but since the *Curve Index* socket accepts fields (multiple values), we can take advantage of that to automatically create as many copies as we have splines. We can get the *Spline Count* from a `Domain Size` node. Then we turn our main object into an instance using `Geometry to Instance` and duplicate it using a `Duplicate Elements`. We could use its other modes, like *Face* (or *Edge*), but that creates individual, disconnected faces (or edges) and you are limited to that particular geometry element—using *Instance* guarantees that the object stays intact as a whole so I prefer duplicating as instance and then *realizing* them later if needed. Finally, the *Duplicate Index* socket allows us to match each copy with a spline:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So simple and elegant...

Comment: @FredI.R. Thanks!

Comment: What are the use of the Map range and the Bounding Box a simple Position will do, doesn't it?

Comment: @FredI.R. If I only used *Position*, negative and >1 values get cut off: https://i.imgur.com/xvVrYAn.mp4 So I'm forcing them all into the 0-1 range.

Comment: Thank you Kuboa! This was extremely helpful and informative!

Answer (score 3):

First there is a solution for the [deformation along a curve in GN](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245282/how-to-bend-geometry-with-geometry-nodes/245553#245553), for the disconnected Curves you can iterate an offset of each of your mesh vertices on the X axe so all the mesh except the first one will go on the next curve and so on.

[image]

As the first is already placed you will have to repeat this process n-1 time (n is the number of your mesh).

[image: Iteration for 25 mesh]

But first you have to make sure all of your mesh share the same location.

[image]

And you have to know the number of point of one mesh, a Domain Size will do the trick.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Fred! This was helpful as well!