# Geometry nodes tries to join splines when deforming mesh along a curve object

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, splines

EDITED: I'm trying to deform copies of a mesh-cube along a curve (and eventually animating them moving along the curve). My problem is that as I'm drawing multiple splines for the curve, the objects are deforming in the space between end of one spline and start of the other. How could I make it so that this "glitchy" deformation between the splines wouldn't happen (and both splines would have the cubes along them)?

[image: Geometry node setup, the black framed part is creating the circles and adding each with an offset along the curve (so that they dont spawn on the same point)]

[image: What the problem looks like, the "glitchy" part is between the splines.]

Comment: Perhaps you should make this clear: I'm not sure, but you appear to be instancing objects along a curve (aligned).. not _deforming_ objects with the curve?

Comment: @RobinBetts thanks that's a good point! I now changed the objects to be cubes rather than circles so that the deformation is visible. I also bumped up the resolutions so node-network should be easier to read

Comment: It's not trying to "join splines" per se, it's just that when one side of your face is still on the end of the first spline and the other side is moved to the start of the second one, they naturally stretch in between. The solution would really depend on what exactly you want to see though. Do you want to just delete the stretched faces? But then the ends of your cubes would be "open", for ex. Do you want them scaled to zero as they travel, then new copies created on the second? Will there be a 3rd, 4th? Mayyybe this would be helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/282932/71578