# How to Copy and Deform Array on each spline with Sample Curve?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Based on [@Robin Betts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/35559/robin-betts)'s sample - [how to bend geometry with geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245282/how-to-bend-geometry-with-geometry-nodes/245553#245553)

If the curves have multiple splines,
How to Copy and Deform on each spline?

or other implementation methods(Not Instance on Points)

Thanks.

[image]

**Update:**

Thanks to [@Robin Betts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/35559/robin-betts) and [@Kuboå](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/71578/kubo%C3%A5), I figured out what I need.

Here is the solution:

[Apply a copy of an object to each disconnected curve using the curve modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282910/apply-a-copy-of-an-object-to-each-disconnected-curve-using-the-curve-modifier?rq=3)

Comment: You want a separate copy of your deformed mesh on each spline?

Comment: Yes, copy and deformed on each spline, therefore the input array(deformed mesh) is as long as the longest spline.

Comment: How do you want the surplus geometry, (too long) on the shorter splines to behave? scaled. lower count. deleted mesh.. etc etc.  Oh, and what Blender version?

Comment: The problem is just like the curve modifier does not support Curves with multiple splines. The Curve Index in Sample Curve Node doesn't help (All Curves Off). I think if that sampling on each spline separately, by your way, we just need an x-array as long as the longest spline. the work is done. Array and Deforming on each spline in a curve.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Ahh! .. and [Kuboå 's deform method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/282932/35559), trimming the curves,  is so much snappier than mine, anyway .. FusioN .. I would definitely recommend it. If it does turn out to be a fix for you, could you confirm in a comment, here, please? We can close this Q. as a duplicate. I'll link from my deform method to Kuboå 's.

Comment: OK, But I'm still struggling with what I am doing, and need to learn how to use StackExchange.

Comment: No problem.. has kuboa's method worked for you? Wouldn't want to combine the questions, unless you had a fix.

Comment: AFK now, for lazy people like me, what you care about above, I just delete the useless. The Array Instance on each spline is the longest(length of the longest spline).when this array deforms on a shorter spline(sample curve by length via position-x), the end of items will collapse, merge by distance, then delete Geometry by Comparing their sum of points or face areas with the original.