# Geometry Nodes Curve deform array on multiple splines

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, boolean-modifier, splines

Since I seem to have made it too complicated. My goal is to line up objects with deform on a curve, but in order not to constantly use a new curve, it should also work with several splines of a curve.
[image]

That was just my approach.

[ Now it works that the arrays act on several splines, but since the instances always only take the entire lenght of all splines and the remaining geometry that cannot be mapped on spline is scaled together.

Then I figured you could use a boolean node to trim the array geometry to the correct length of each spline. The problem then is that you would have to split the boolean geometry into individual parts and reassemble them into a whole instance per spline in order to address them again at each individual spline ID.

I have mention that it's more of a piece of cakework and I don't have a deeper understanding of geometry nodes.

That's why I'm asking, does it make sense to even try something like this in terms of performance?

This is the node group I use for the curve deformation (X_Curve_Deform)
[how to bend geometry with geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245282/how-to-bend-geometry-with-geometry-nodes)
. This solution is for multiple splines
[Apply a copy of an object to each disconnected curve using the curve modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282910/apply-a-copy-of-an-object-to-each-disconnected-curve-using-the-curve-modifier/282932#282932)
. Perhaps this question and solution could help
[Array deformed along multiple disconnected splines](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/290882/array-deformed-along-multiple-disconnected-splines)
.]

My nodetree
[image]

the Spline_length_03 group

[image]
[image]
[image]

I want to use the boolean operation to cut them to fit the length of each spline but when i do this it also join all to one single mesh. Now i have to split the mesh in (this example 3) seperate instances or meshes and reordered them on the splines. At end the curve deform operation will do the rest. I don't know how to explain it better, one goal is, for example to draw multiple chains on a character for instance. It works for now but the all vertices/Faces witch not fit to the spline will scaled down and its generate zero faces. I would try to avoid this.

Comment: Could you state your goal in simpler terms, before describing  the method? I'm guessing you mean you want to trim multiple ordered splines continuously, from the end of spline n to the start of spline 0

Comment: Ate you trying to avoid clipping? There are two ways,  **one is** to extend it passed the bounds of the curve, **the other is** to use the bounding box of the instances to scale it down to fit within the bounds of the curve.