# Select an object in a collection with Duplicate Element

Tags: geometry-nodes, collections, duplicate

Is it possible to give a collection to a *Duplicate Element* node and select which object we want to duplicate ? Somehow like the *instance on point* node.

I've tried to use the selection socket but I can't figure out how to have only separated elements.

I'm trying to modify [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/282910/apply-a-copy-of-an-object-to-each-disconnected-curve-using-the-curve-modifier/282932#282932) from @Kuboå to be able to use different objects on each curve.

Edit : I'm doing this to be able to replace the hair strands of an hair dynamics simulation (.abc files) with random hair cards (a collection). I haven't found a way to scatter randomly the cards on one hair sim, so I use multiple hair simulation.

Comment: Can you flesh out a bit to explain what you mean exactly,  by 'multiple instances in the same GN''? Many on one curve? Different on each curve?

Comment: The best would be different on each curves. 
I'm trying to use hair dynamics on hair cards. For that I export the hair simulation into an abc file. Because I couldn't find a way to use different object on each hair, I use multiple particle system. Now, I'm trying to avoid to have to link each object to each particle system manually.

Comment: Hi, @Simon .. IMO there's a risk of [XY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), here. Personally. I think it would be better to describe what you've got as a starting state, and exactly where you want to wind up, in an edit of the question itself.